# [Multiprocessing Python]Return 2 values have error'too many values to unpack (expected 1)'

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I used Multiprocessing in Python and get error 'too many values to unpack (expected 1)'. Anyone can fix it? Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(n):
    return n*n, n*n*n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=3)
    double_result, triple_result = p.map(f,[1,2,3,4,5])
    for n in double_result:
        print(n)
    for n in triple_result:
        print(n)
```

Comment: `map` will return a sequence of results, one for each input. There are 5 inputs so 5 results.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
double_result, triple_result = list(zip(*p.map(f, [1,2,3,4,5])))
```

Comment: I think it should be:
double_result, triple_result = list(zip(*p.map(f, [1,2,3,4,5])))
for Multiprocessing purpose.

Comment: Yes my bad when I tested I didn't use Pool so used the normal `map` but you should use `p.map`. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if you are using a Jupyter notebook:

Create a function called `f(n)` and save it as `f.py`:

like this:

```
def f(n):
    results = n*n, n*n*n        
    return results
```

Then, call this function as the following:

```
# to import f.py:
import sys
# use the folder path of f.py
sys.path.insert(1, r'full_path\folder_name_where_f.py_is_found')

import multiprocessing
import f

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(f, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print("Output n*n: {}".format([result[0] for result in results]))
print("Output n*n*n: {}".format([result[1] for result in results]))
```

Output:

```
Output n*n: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
Output n*n*n: [1, 8, 27, 64, 125]
```

Enjoy!